# Altera Quartus "Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified...", how to suppress?

Tags: intel-fpga, quartus

My Altera Quartus builds show this warning...

```
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
```

How do I suppress this warning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this tcl expression...

```
set_global_assignment -name NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS ALL
```

... to either assignment_defaults.qdf or the .qsf file. Both should be in the project's directory. The .qdf file may need to be created.

Comment: Probably worth marking this as accepted to stop the system bumping it back to the homepage.

Comment: There is also an option to use all available processors, which also gets rid of the warning, and adjusts the setting to whatever machine the compile runs on.

Comment: @SimonRichter, what name and value would be used?

Comment: @JimFred `set_global_assignment -name NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS ALL`

Answer (score 2):

Many recommend creating assignment_defaults.qdf in project's directory, but then each project would contain unnecessary file just to get rid of this warning. I wanted to add this to global config in Linux but googling turned up either nothing or deprecated information. I ended up using strace to find global config file:

```
/opt/quartus/quartus/linux64/assignment_defaults.qdf
```

After adding `set_global_assignment -name NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS ALL` to it the warning was gone in all projects.